# How to adjust taskwarrior report height?

Tags: taskwarrior

With the command `task next`, taskwarrior produces a report of urgent next tasks. The report is apparently scaled to the terminal height.

I use zshell with a special prompt which is 2-lines high. Because of this, taskwarrior appears to be miscalculating the max height, and I end up with the next tasks table header hidden from view.

Is there a way to adjust how the next tasks report calculates terminal height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your `.taskrc`:

```
reserved.lines = 2 # 2 if your promt is 2 lines high,
                   # 3 if it inserts a break before prompt
```

of course, you can also do it directly using `rc.OPTION`, in this case:

```
$ task rc.reserved.lines=2
```

For more info, check `$ man taskrc`.

NOTE: `reserved.lines` does **not** work with `$ task burndown`, if your `$ task --version` is less than `2.6.0`. See: [#2020](https://github.com/GothenburgBitFactory/taskwarrior/issues/2020).